# Not able to fetch data from dynamodb from lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch data from dynamodb from my lambda.I have written this code

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-south-1'});


var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
          TableName: 'my_table',
          Key: {
                      'serial_number': {S: '17AB-574C-C1'}
                    },

};


ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
                console.log("Success", data.Item);
                console.log(data);
        }
});

};
```

This code works fine when I run locally but I get a null response when I run it on lambda.My lambda has dynamoDbfullAccess policy attached to it. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you paste the Lambda logs here?

Comment: Nothing in the logs just this. START RequestId: 16ca8288-c038-4f69-845e-c3f8ce1cc3d3 Version: $LATEST END RequestId: 16ca8288-c038-4f69-845e-c3f8ce1cc3d3 REPORT RequestId: 16ca8288-c038-4f69-845e-c3f8ce1cc3d3 Duration: 4443.24 ms Billed Duration: 4500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB Init Duration: 114.55 ms

Comment: That is all the log you get?

Comment: Yes. When I try to console something in this block ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data)  it is not getting print.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I am getting similar issue